# How to kick on specific message

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to auto-kick people with my discord bot when they send an invite link, but `message.author.kick()` doesn't seem to work. I've also tried other variations of it, like `member.kick()`.

This is my code so far:

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.includes('discord.gg/')) {
    message.channel.send('Nope');
    message.delete(3000);
    message.author.kick('posting links');
  }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! "Nothing seems to work" - please revise your description to include better detail along the lines of "<what is happening> and< how this is different to what you want to happen>" - you should always avoid saying something bland and generic like "it doesn't work" or "it gave some error" when asking for help on SO

Comment: what happens if you log the message object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.author` gives a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object that you can't kick. You have to kick a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember): you can obtain the author's member object by using `message.member`.

Here is the correction of your code:

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.includes('discord.gg/')) {
    message.channel.send('Nope');
    message.delete(3000);
    message.member.kick('posting links');
  }
});
```